# How can I call already made API to feed other API specific variable?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I made one API in Django which helps me to give the list of all Hospitals and I also assign some namespace for this url

```
url(r'hospital_list$', HospitalList.as_view(), namespace="hospital-list"),

class HospitalList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(HospitalSerializer(instance=Hospitals.objects.all(), many=True).data)
```

Response of this API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Apollo Bangalore Cradle Ltd."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Apollo Bangalore Cradle Ltd."
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Apollo Hospitals"
    },
    ..
    ..
    ..

]
```

I am making another API where I want to feed data of one variable(hospital_list) which will come from the first API.

```
path('profile/', AgentProfile.as_view()),

class AgentProfile(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    def get(self, request):
        usr = request.user
        lead_objs = Leads.objects.filter(agent__id=usr.id)

        hospital_list = request.get()------> here I am getting confusion how I will use namespace

        return Response({"hospital_list":hospital_list,
                         "total_lead": lead_objs.count()})
```

How can I call the namespace URL and save the response in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you want to call `HospitalList` from within `AgentProfile` which can be achieved like so:

```
path('profile/', AgentProfile.as_view()),

class AgentProfile(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get(self, request):
        usr = request.user
        lead_objs = Leads.objects.filter(agent__id=usr.id)

        hospital_list = HospitalList.get(self, request)     # Call other view here

        return Response({"hospital_list":hospital_list,
                         "total_lead": lead_objs.count()})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.